# How to test if a given text column is a valid oid

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, typechecking

In PL/pgSQL, I have a column that may or may not contain an `oid`. I need to detect if it does or not.

At the moment I do it like this:

```
  select oidtext from t into x where name = fname;
  if found then
    begin
        select x::oid into looid;
    exception
        when SQLSTATE '22P02' then -- invalid oid    
           null;
```

but this feels a bit hacky. Is there a positive test, i.e. "is this text column a valid x type", or "is this a valid cast"?

Comment: Generic OIDs or object identifiers of a certain kind, like `regclass`, 'regproc` etc.?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter in my case the oid would be a largeobject oid

Comment: There are convenient functions for common object identifiers: `to_regclass()`, `to_regproc()`, etc. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE But not for large object IDs. Is it enough that the value is a valid OID, or do you actually want to check whether it's a valid `pg_largeobject.loid`?

Comment: i want to test if its a valid oid, I know its either an lo oid or a guid

Comment: Then I would consider with Laurenz' function, since functions with an exception clause are considerably more expensive.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the only way is to catch an exception, but you can do it in a handy function like this:

```
create or replace function oid_or_null(text)
returns oid language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
    return $1::oid;
exception when invalid_text_representation then
    return null;
end $$;

select oid_or_null('123'), oid_or_null('abc');

 oid_or_null | oid_or_null 
-------------+-------------
         123 |            
(1 row)
```

You can create a more generic boolean function:

```
create or replace function is_valid_cast(text, text)
returns boolean language plpgsql immutable as $$
begin
    execute format('select %L::%I', $1, $2);
    return true;
exception when others then
    return false;
end $$;

select 
    is_valid_cast('123', 'oid') as oid, is_valid_cast('abc', 'oid') as not_oid,
    is_valid_cast('2018-10-10', 'date') as date, is_valid_cast('2018-20-20', 'date') as not_date;

 oid | not_oid | date | not_date 
-----+---------+------+----------
 t   | f       | t    | f
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution doesn't need to capture errors:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_oid(text) RETURNS boolean
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$$SELECT CASE WHEN trim(leading '0' from $1) ~ '^\d{1,10}$'
              THEN $1::bigint BETWEEN 0 AND 4294967295
              ELSE FALSE
         END$$;
```

An `oid` is a 4-byte unsigned integer, so it must consist of no more than 10 digits and be between 0 and 4294967295.

Comment: I thought about a similar approach but such a *parsing* may be a bit inaccurate, e.g. `'01234567890'::oid` is valid.

Comment: I didn't think of that; fixed.

Comment: the point is that there are no builtin generic  trycast or istype functions. I will stick with my exception based method then

Comment: Or `CASE WHEN $1 ~ '^0*\d{1,10}$' ... THEN $1::bigint < 4294967296 ...`